# NodeJS - Is host reacheable without ICMP

Tags: node.js

I've the need to check if an host is reacheable or not. This machine have ICMP protocol disabled, so i can't send a simple "ping" on it.

The machine is up, network is ok but i cant ping it.

There is a way to "understand" if an host is reacheable without using ICMP ? (like nmap).

Another point, i will have to do this on Windows and Linux, my NodeJS application should work on "any" OS.

Thanks

Comment: Reachable on what port(s)?

Comment: One for [sf] or [networkengineering.se]?

Comment: Thanks, i will post this answare there

Comment: Because it has nothing to do with node.js.